# Converting Albert to tflite (Albert implemented in Keras via bert-for-tf2)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite

I am having a hard time converting albert (more specifically, albert_base model) to tflite. Here is my code defining my model using bert-for-tf2 (https://github.com/kpe/bert-for-tf2) <- thanks for this great implementation by the way...

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Flatten, AveragePooling1D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import bert
import sentencepiece as spm


def load_pretrained_albert():
    model_name = "albert_base"
    albert_dir = bert.fetch_tfhub_albert_model(model_name, ".models")
    model_params = bert.albert_params(model_name)
    l_bert = bert.BertModelLayer.from_params(model_params, name="albert")

    # use in Keras Model here, and call model.build()
    max_seq_len = 128

    l_input_ids = Input(shape=(max_seq_len,), dtype='float32', name="l_input_ids")

    output = l_bert(l_input_ids)                             
    pooled_output = AveragePooling1D(pool_size=max_seq_len, data_format="channels_last")(output)
    pooled_output = Flatten()(pooled_output)   # poooled_output: [batch_size, embedding_dimension=768]

    model = Model(inputs=[l_input_ids], outputs=[pooled_output])
    model.build(input_shape=(None, max_seq_len))

    bert.load_albert_weights(l_bert, albert_dir)

    return model
```

But when I try to convert the model to tflite with the following code,

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(m)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

the following error occurs :

```
File "C:\Users\hygki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\lite\python\lite.py", line 405, in convert
    self._funcs[0], lower_control_flow=False)
  File "C:\Users\hygki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\convert_to_constants.py", line 575, in convert_variables_to_constants_v2
    converted_input_indices)
  File "C:\Users\hygki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\convert_to_constants.py", line 371, in _construct_concrete_function
    new_output_names)
  File "C:\Users\hygki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\wrap_function.py", line 620, in function_from_graph_def
    wrapped_import = wrap_function(_imports_graph_def, [])
  File "C:\Users\hygki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\wrap_function.py", line 598, in wrap_function
    collections={}),
  File "C:\Users\hygki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 915, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hygki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\wrap_function.py", line 83, in __call__
    return self.call_with_variable_creator_scope(self._fn)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hygki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\wrap_function.py", line 89, in wrapped
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hygki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\wrap_function.py", line 618, in _imports_graph_def
    importer.import_graph_def(graph_def, name="")
  File "C:\Users\hygki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\util\deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hygki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\importer.py", line 405, in import_graph_def
    producer_op_list=producer_op_list)
  File "C:\Users\hygki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\importer.py", line 505, in _import_graph_def_internal
    raise ValueError(str(e))
ValueError: Input 0 of node model/albert/embeddings/word_embeddings/embedding_lookup was passed float from model/albert/embeddings/word_embeddings/embedding_lookup/Read/ReadVariableOp/resource:0 incompatible with expected resource.
```

So instead, I tried saving the model in the saved_model format and retried converting with the following code :

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model('saved_model_path')
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

However, again an identical error message appeared.

```
File "C:\Users\hygki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\lite\python\lite.py", line 405, in convert
    self._funcs[0], lower_control_flow=False)
  File "C:\Users\hygki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\convert_to_constants.py", line 575, in convert_variables_to_constants_v2
    converted_input_indices)
  File "C:\Users\hygki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\convert_to_constants.py", line 371, in _construct_concrete_function
    new_output_names)
  File "C:\Users\hygki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\wrap_function.py", line 620, in function_from_graph_def
    wrapped_import = wrap_function(_imports_graph_def, [])
  File "C:\Users\hygki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\wrap_function.py", line 598, in wrap_function
    collections={}),
  File "C:\Users\hygki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 915, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hygki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\wrap_function.py", line 83, in __call__
    return self.call_with_variable_creator_scope(self._fn)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hygki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\wrap_function.py", line 89, in wrapped
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hygki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\wrap_function.py", line 618, in _imports_graph_def
    importer.import_graph_def(graph_def, name="")
  File "C:\Users\hygki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\util\deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hygki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\importer.py", line 405, in import_graph_def
    producer_op_list=producer_op_list)
  File "C:\Users\hygki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\importer.py", line 505, in _import_graph_def_internal
    raise ValueError(str(e))
ValueError: Input 0 of node StatefulPartitionedCall/model/albert/embeddings/word_embeddings/embedding_lookup was passed float from Func/StatefulPartitionedCall/input/_2:0 incompatible with expected resource.
```

So what I understood is that the embedding_lookup is fed with float when the expected data type is not float. But what is the expected data type? Is there a way that I can find out? Also, is there a workaround for this problem?

Any help for my struggle with converting albert_base to tflite formtat will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the "IdentityN " error, did you try to convert it with SELECT_TF_OPS?
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select

Comment: Yes!  That worked out perfectly! Thank you very much :)

Comment: for those who are trying to find out how to do that in python api, do the following :

`def to_lite(path):
    converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(path)
    converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS,
                                       tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]
    lite_albert = converter.convert()
    return lite_albert`

Answer (score 0):

Funny that I have been struggling with the problem for hours but only right after I uploaded question I solved the problem...

So the solution is, use tensorflow version 1.15.0!
Using tensorflow2 seems to cause the issue.

However, I still cannot convert the model to tflite since it does not support 'IdentityN' ops yet. I don't think I can write a custom op myself, so I think I should just wait for tflite update....

Answer (score 0):

Use the ALBERT 2.0 ( tf 2.0 ) model from the official repo. Change https://github.com/google-research/ALBERT/blob/master/modeling.py#L516 to `tf.gather(tf.identity(embedding_table), input_ids)` . Then try convert using tflite as before. In case not, please comment here.